# terraria pink dungeon wall

Tags: terraria

I created a wolrd with the `TerraCustom v0.3.6` editor because i wanted a pink dungeon to harvest the stuff.

I can dig the walls but I can not remove the background wall, allthough this was possible in the Green and Blue Dungeon (this one also created with `TerraCustom`).

Is this a Bug? Of the the editor? Of the game? Or does they require hammers of different strength?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

Background can be harvested as soon as Skeletron is slain.